# Need to ignore property in XmlSerialization because of circular reference

Tags: xml-serialization

Have an object with a property I don't need to serialize. The type of this property generates a circular reference which I expected, so I decorated this property with everything comes to my mind:

```
private clsDeclaracion _Declaracion;
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
public clsDeclaracion Declaracion
{
  get { return _Declaracion; }
  set { _Declaracion = value; }
}
```

However, the circular reference keeps firing. Tried using a public field with no luck. 
This is my serialization code:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer Serializador =
            new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(objeto.GetType());

using (StreamWriter SW = System.IO.File.CreateText(ArchivoTemp))
{
  Serializador.Serialize(SW, objeto);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking here and there it turns out the circular reference was not in the class stated in the exception, it was a little deeper.